# jQuery: Change text and class on click while preserving the child elements

Tags: jquery, text, toggle, children, toggleclass

I'm trying to do a simple "toggle" like function with jQuery but I can’t seem to get it to work quite the right way.

I've a HTML block which looks like this:

```
<li class="item-actions-follow">
    <a href="#" id="follow" class="icon small-icon circle_plus">
        <i></i>
            Follow
    </a>
</li>
```

I would like to, when a user clicks on the link "Follow" to change the class **circle_plus** on the a `href` tag to **circle_minus** and to change the text **Follow** to **Unfollow** and vice versa.

I tried some different things but they all come close but not exactly what I want.

Within a jQuery event "onclick" I do this:

```
var text = $("a#follow").text() == 'Follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow';
$("a#follow").text(text);
```

That did change the text "Follow" to "Unfollow" but not back when I clicked the link again **and** it removed the tag `<i></i>` which is essentially to display the icon which is provided by the **circle_plus** class.

I also tried to do a pure Toggle (I later found out that the Toggle function does not work on text but only properties), like this:

```
$("a#follow").toggle
function() {
$("a#follow").text("Unfollow");
$(this).removeClass('circle_plus').addClass('circle_minus').stop();
      },
      function() {
        $("a#follow").text("Follow");
        $(this).removeClass('circle_minus').addClass('circle_plus').stop();
      });
```

When I do this and click the link, it just “fade” out the text and icon all together, doesn’t even change the class.

I also tried the `.toggleClass()` function but with no luck.

I'm relatively new to jQuery so it might be a simple task but I've looked wide for a solution but with no luck so far.

Hope you can help me pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the text inside a span: `<a id="follow"><i></i><span>follow</span></a>`

I'd do it the oldschool way:

```
$('#follow').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('circle_plus')) {
        $(this).removeClass('circle_plus').addClass('circle_minus').find('span').text('unfollow');
    }
    else {
        // vice versa
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not wrapped the element inside another element, there is empty content in it.

Just add `.trim()` to remove the empty space..

This should be good

```
$('#follow').on('click', function () {
    var $elem = $("#follow");
    $elem.text().trim() === 'Follow' ? $elem.text('UnFollow')
                                     : $elem.text('Follow');
    $elem.toggleClass('circle_plus circle_minus')
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/f8BWN/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Are you wrapping this in the click function handler? 
take a look at this fiddle its working

http://jsfiddle.net/qq8f3/5/

HTML

`<a href="#" id="follow">Follow</a>`

CSS

```
#follow.circle_plus{background-color:red;}
```

JS

```
$("a#follow").click(function(){
var link = $("a#follow");
var text = link.text() == 'Follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow';
link.text(text);
link.toggleClass('circle_plus');
return false;});
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you could do something like this, reduces you `js` "overhead" (although very little). As you can see, I've changed the markup a bit.

**HTML:**

```
<li class="item-actions-follow"> <a href="#" id="follow" class="icon small-icon">
        <span class="circle_plus">
            <i></i>
            Follow
        </span>
        <span class="circle_minus">
            <i></i>
            UnFollow
        </span>
    </a>    
</li>
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$("a#follow").click(function(){
    $(this).children("span").toggle();
});
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/LGB6w/)